# How Did Moses Build The Bronze Serpent and How Long Did It Take For Him To Do It?

Tags: history, moshe-rabbeinu, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

How Did Moses Build The Bronze Serpent and How Long Did It Take For Him To Do It?

Numbers 21:1-9

> And when king Arad the Canaanite, which dwelt in the south, heard tell
> that Israel came by the way of the spies; then he fought against
> Israel, and took some of them prisoners.
>
> And Israel vowed a vow unto the Lord, and said, If thou wilt indeed
> deliver this people into my hand, then I will utterly destroy their
> cities.
>
> And the Lord hearkened to the voice of Israel, and delivered up the
> Canaanites; and they utterly destroyed them and their cities: and he
> called the name of the place Hormah.
>
> And they journeyed from mount Hor by the way of the Red sea, to
> compass the land of Edom: and the soul of the people was much
> discouraged because of the way.
>
> And the people spake against God, and against Moses, Wherefore have ye
> brought us up out of Egypt to die in the wilderness? for there is no
> bread, neither is there any water; and our soul loatheth this light
> bread.
>
> And the Lord sent fiery serpents among the people, and they bit the
> people; and much people of Israel died.
>
> Therefore the people came to Moses, and said, We have sinned, for we
> have spoken against the Lord, and against thee; pray unto the Lord,
> that he take away the serpents from us. And Moses prayed for the
> people.
>
> And the Lord said unto Moses, Make thee a fiery serpent, and set it
> upon a pole: and it shall come to pass, that every one that is bitten,
> when he looketh upon it, shall live.
>
> And Moses made a serpent of brass, and put it upon a pole, and it came
> to pass, that if a serpent had bitten any man, when he beheld the
> serpent of brass, he lived.

Comment: Are you asking how long it takes to mine נְח֔שֶׁת Copper in אֱד֑וֹם Edom?

Comment: Thank you for inquiring and basically what I am asking is how did Moses build the serpent and what would be the amount of time that took him to build it. The story makes it seem like it happened fairly quickly but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think anyone addresses this because it is not material to understanding the story.